# C++: passing gameobject as a parameter and then into vector

Tags: c++, sdl2, gameobject, objects, memory

firstly iam used to java and new to c++ so maybe this will looks a noob's question
i will explain this and give a pseudo code and then c++ just so you can understand me

i have a **player** class which inherit from **gameobject** and a **handler** class which update all the game objects(stored in vector) and render them
i have a function to add objects but i get errors every time (i work with SDL2 if this gonna help)

**pseudo code**:

```
///some class
handler hand = new handler();
gameObject pla = new player();
hand.addObject(pla);  ----> here

/// handler class 

vector<gameObject> objects;

void addObjects(gameObject object) 
{
   objects.push(object);  ------> specially here
}
```

**C++ code**

```
/// game class

handler hand = new handler();
gameobject* pla = new player();
hand->addobject(pla); 

/// handler class

vector<gameobject*> objects;

void addobject(gameobject* object)
{
    objects.push_back(object); -----> here
}
```

i have searched for a week and nothing 
i used **unique_ptr** but nothing
every time new error some times **std::bad_alloc** sometimes **objects has been deleted**

i am confused please guide me to the right way to do this

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your crashes is mostly because of improper handling of the object's ownership.

When you add something to a collection, you should clearly understand who's owning the object. Is that handler owns the added objects now, and may delete those when time has come? Or is that handler only references the objects, and there's some other subsystem that will destroy the objects? Get clear with ownership first, because implementation will differ.

Assigning `unique_ptr` to a collection assumes ownership is transferred to that collection. There's no other way to `push_back` the `unique_ptr` into a `vector`. There can't be multiple copies of the same `unique_ptr`. Well, technically you could construct multiple `unique_ptr` from the very same raw pointer, but that's a big no-no.

In case your `handler` will own the objects, the next example is possible:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

using std::vector;
using std::unique_ptr;
using std::move;

/// gameobjec base class
class gameobject
{
public:
    virtual ~gameobject() {};
};

/// player class
class player: public gameobject
{
public:
    float* some_data;

    player(int map_size)
    {
        some_data = new float[map_size];
    }

    ~player()
    {
        delete[] some_data;
    }
};

/// handler class
class handler
{
public:
    vector<gameobject*> objects;
    vector<unique_ptr<gameobject> > objects_auto;

    void addobject(gameobject* object)
    {
        objects.push_back(object);
    }


    void addobject(unique_ptr<gameobject>& object)
    {
        objects_auto.push_back(move(object));
    }

    void add_raw_to_auto(gameobject* object)
    {
        objects_auto.push_back(unique_ptr<gameobject>(object));
    }

    ~handler()
    {
        // objects behind raw pointers must be explicitly deleted
        for(auto obj: objects)
            delete obj;

        // nothing needs to be done about unique_ptr containers
    }
};

int main()
{
    handler* hand = new handler();

    for(int i=0; i<100; ++i)
    {
        // add raw pointer to a collection of raw pointers
        gameobject* pla = new player(i);
        hand->addobject(pla);

        // add unique_ptr to a collection of unique_ptr
        unique_ptr<gameobject> pla_auto(new player(i*2));
        hand->addobject(pla_auto);

        // add raw pointer to a collection of unique ptr
        gameobject* pla_raw = new player(i);
        hand->add_raw_to_auto(pla_raw);
    }

    delete hand;
}
```

Since in `handler` you're storing the pointer to a base class, you should make virtual destructor there, so the collections of pointers to different objects inherited from that base class will be properly destroyed. A memory leaks are possible if the base class' destructor isn't virtual.

Comment: but 
the first addobject method don't work i tried it 
and it say 
what():std::_bad_alloc

Comment: @younlok The crash is likely in the code you didn't show. This example works ok: https://ideone.com/StLMx2  and passes the Valgrind checks.

Comment: maybe the class is small that's why it works 
but i have problem with this that why i was confused and i showed all the code that has relation to the problem

Comment: and i read that if its more than one file this will also cause a problem

Comment: @younlok The class size isn't important, unless there's gigabytes of arrays inside. Every program is built from many files, it's not a factor here too, unless you only recompile one file ignoring dependencies. You showed the spot which triggers the bug, but it's not the spot that's causes the bug. Try to build a minimal program that reproduces the crash. Run it under Valgrind and see the exact trace to the spot where it crashes, then you could find the real cause.

Comment: i mean big stuff what causes those problems 
classes are big that's why u get std::bad_alloc you are throwing them  on the stack 
that's what i read 
i will wait for another answer
thank you sir so much

Comment: and i tried it like your way but its not working
i don't know 
but if i don't call the function its all right 
and i debugg it and the problem is inthe func

Comment: @younlok there's no point in guessing. Just make minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example , or run your sw under Valgrind-like profiling tool to find the cause of the crash. Did you even try to run it under debugger to see the stack trace?

Comment: when i do a minimal example it works because the class isn't big but when i make the class big i get errors it has something to do with memory and stuff 
and i tried with debugger

Comment: @younlok How "big" you think it needs to be to expose the issue? The minimal/reproducible is called `reproducible` for a reason - it must include the code that gives issue. Without profiling/debugging the reproducible example, and without full project - the guessing is meaningless. It might be even something absolutely not related to `.push_back()` call, simply because you're calling the `addobject()` method on an invalid pointer instead of valid pointer to the live `handler` object. So the crash is caused by something outside of the scope of the code you've shown.

Comment: the problem is  when i push to the vector 
i tried some debugging and the problem is there 
i think the problem is copying and memory stuff

Comment: @younlok by the moment you're pushing the data onto vector, it's likely you're already past the point that's causing issue. So the vector's methods will crash because you've passed wrong data to it - wrong `this`, or pointer to already destroyed object, etc.

Comment: i am not doing anything with the the objects inside vector i just add them for now 
and i tried to print somestuff before and after pushing 
and yeah the first  one printed but the second no